# how to play an asx file in flash

Tags: php, flash, streaming

i need to steam an .ask file form an remote site is it is possible to do in flash ......
..

Answer (score 0):

Flash cannot directly stream this format. You will have to use a server-side proxy that first converts asx to flv. At least judging from the comment #6 on this blog ffmpeg can do the conversion: http://www.bokko.nl/?p=80